# I'm getting JavaScript error "d.getMonth is not a function" when trying to format a date using d3.time.format

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, date-format, time-format

I have a date value `2016-02-18` and I want to convert it to `Feb 18`.

I tried the following code, but it returns an error that `get.month` is  not a function. I have also tried using `format.parse()`, but that didn't work either.

#### My code :

```
var dateLast = "2016-02-18";
var date = Date.parse(dateLast.replace(/-/g,"/"));
var format =  d3.time.format("%b-%d");
var dateConvert = format(date);
console.log(dateConvert);
```

#### The error message :

> TypeError: d.getMonth is not a function at d3_time_formats.b
>   (d3.js:2517) at format (d3.js:2431)

Comment: which version of `d3` are you using, and on which browser does the error happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The D3.js way :

Using `d3.time.format`, the most efficient way to achieve what you're going for, is this :

```
var dateLast = "2016-02-18";
var format = d3.time.format("%b %d");
var dateConvert = format(new Date(dateLast));

alert(dateConvert); // Output : Feb 18
```

(See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/of6wdnu6/))

So, basically, you don't need this `dateLast.replace` or `Date.parse` at all. You can just use your date string directly as input of `new Date()`.

---

#### The vanilla JS way :

Personally, I wouldn't even use d3 (or any other library) at all to format dates. You can do it in vanilla JS with about the same amount of code :

```js
var dateLast = "2016-02-18";
var format = { month : 'short', day : 'numeric' };
var dateConvert = new Date(dateLast).toLocaleDateString('en-US', format);

alert(dateConvert); // Output : Feb 18
```

(See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/51jsb080/)).

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass `Date` object into `format` function (see [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#_format)):

```
var dateLast = "2016-02-18";
var date = Date.parse(dateLast.replace(/-/g,"/"))
var format = d3.time.format("%b-%d");
var dateConvert = format(new Date(date))
console.log(dateConvert)
```

Comment: Yes, yet another javascript gotcha - `Date.parse` doesn't return a `Date`.